# Is this question too broad?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[Can you deduce absolute motion through magnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252869/)

I loved above question. All my doubts at one place.

But is it too broad?
It seems to ask a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes, *absolutely* too broad. It asks six different questions, and should have been posted as six different posts. (Maybe 4 or 5 if a couple of the questions can be consolidated.)

Since this is such an egregious case, I've removed the bounty and put the question on hold.

Comment: Can links be provided to each question ? I would love some easy navigation.

Comment: To which questions?

Comment: I think many parts are duplicates.

Comment: And, most of the various parts were only questions because off fundamental misunderstanding on the OPs side about relativity.